# I've got a Feather, What's It For?

Tags: moon-hunters

I threatened some kind of weird Demon Bird that was harassing a friendly priestess by getting all up in her holy tree, and the bird turned and ran, because I'm one scary mother. Great. The bird also dropped an "Anzu Feather", which the game describes as a "Key Item". Also Great.

Now what the hell do I do with an Anzu Feather?

Comment: In my brief time with the game, there is often an NPC somewhere who needs the item. Although it's down to RNG if you find a map with them in.

Comment: I think this one is usable in spirit chambers and stuff like that. Also the Anzu bird-demon can be found on the great tree, so you may have more interactions at that time